# How can I aggregate dictionaries over class hierarchy (Python)

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

Let's say I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A(object):
  _d = {}

class B(A):
  _d = {'b': 1}

class C(A):
  _d = {'b': 2, 'c': 3}

class D(B):
  _d = {'d': 4}
```

Is there a way to write an @property method `d` on `A` which will return the aggregated dictionary over all superclasses of an object?  For example, `B().d` would return `{'b': 1}`, `C().d` would return `{'b': 2, 'c': 3}`, and `D().d` would return `{'b': 1, 'd': 4}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inspect.getmro` to skip any concerns with multiple inheritance and avoid the necessity of a recursive call to get all the subclasses.

```
import inspect

@property
d(self):
    res = {}
    subclasses = inspect.getmro(type(self))
    for cls in reversed(subclasses):
        res.update(gettattr(cls, 'd', {}))
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks - inspect.getmro is good to know about, but I actually want to do this the other way around - find the superclass dicts from the subclass.

Comment: @rfrankel, none of the presented answers do what you want then. All of them take a subclass and in some way, traverse some portion of the tree back up to the superclass. In fact your example is called on a subclass.

Comment: That *is* what I want - my apologies; I think I misunderstood your example (the identifier "subclasses" threw me off).

Answer (score 2):

Well, straightforward solution is to use `__bases__` attribute of the class to traverse inheritance chain. However there are some multiple inheritance issues which may or may not to be a concern for you.

```
 def d(self):
     res = {}
     def traverse(cls):
         if hasattr(cls, '_d'):
             for k,v in cls._d.iteritems():
                 res[k]=v
             for basecls in cls.__bases__:
                 traverse(basecls)
     for k,v in self._d.iteritems():
         res[k]=v
     traverse(self.__class__)
     return res

>>> D().d()
{'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  @property
  def d(self):
    res = dict(self._d)
    for c in self.__class__.__bases__:
        res.update(getattr(c(),'d',{}))
    return res
```